# How do I create nested configuration parameters in a custom gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

How do I create a nested parameter structure in a custom gradle plugin?

For starters, I am using Gradle 7.2. I want to make an expressive DSL-like structure for my plugin configuration, with a nested element

```
fileDiff {
    file1 = file('${testFile1.getName()}')
    file2 = file('${testFile2.getName()}')
                
    messages {
          message1 = 'Hi there'
    }                
}
```

While learning how to write Gradle Plugins I have been following the [gradle plugin implementation docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#modeling_dsl_like_apis), and they are great at showing what to do with the extension but not the "plugin" class.

So I have modeled my extension, `FileDiffExtension` like so

```
abstract class FileDiffExtension {

    abstract RegularFileProperty getFile1()

    abstract RegularFileProperty getFile2()

    @Nested
    abstract Messages getMessages()

    void messages(Action<? super Messages> action) {
        action.execute(getMessages())
    }
}
```

And the nested `Messages` class is modeled as such

```
abstract class Messages {
    abstract Property<String> getMessage1()
}
```

I think I am good up to this point. Then I need to pull my extension into my plugin and this is where I believe I am running into issues. My Plugin class currently looks like

```
class FileDiffPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.tasks.register('fileDiff', FileDiffTask) {
            project.extensions.create('fileDiff', FileDiffExtension)
            project.fileDiff.extensions.create("messages", FileDiffExtension.messages)

            file1 = project.fileDiff.file1
            file2 = project.fileDiff.file2

            messages = project.fileDiff.getMessages
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a `messages` extension off of the root level extension `fileDiff`. Or maybe I am not supposed to set the `messages` object in the task to the getMessages() abstract method. But I have tried every combination I can think of. The actual task is shown below, but I don't think the problem lies here.

```
abstract class FileDiffTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile
    abstract RegularFileProperty getFile1()

    @InputFile
    abstract RegularFileProperty getFile2()

    @Input
    abstract Property<Messages> getMessages()

    @OutputFile
    abstract RegularFileProperty getResultFile()

    FileDiffTask() {
        resultFile.convention(project.layout.buildDirectory.file('diff-result.txt'))
    }

    @TaskAction
    def diff() {
        // Print out the message
        println messages.get().message1.toString()

        // Now we do some fun file stuff
        String diffResult
        if (size(file1) == size(file2)) {
            diffResult = "Files have the same size at ${file1.get().asFile.getBytes()} bytes}"
        } else {
            File largestFile = size(file1) > size(file2) ? file1.get().asFile : file2.get().asFile
            diffResult = "${largestFile.toString()} is the largest file at ${largestFile.size()} bytes"
        }

        resultFile.get().asFile.write diffResult

        println "File written to $resultFile"
        println diffResult
    }

    private static long size(RegularFileProperty regularFileProperty) {
        return regularFileProperty.get().asFile.size()
    }
}
```

To test I am using the gradle test kit, and I'm currently getting the following error.
`

> Could not create task ':fileDiff'.
> No such property: messages for class: com.robschwartz.plugins.filediff.FileDiffExtension
> Possible solutions: messages
> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, according to [docs](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/snippets/developingPlugins/pluginExtension/groovy/buildSrc/src/main/java/org/myorg/SitePlugin.java) you do not need to do anything with the sub-extension if it's marked as `@Nested`, it should just work. Have you tried to remove this line entirely?

```
project.fileDiff.extensions.create("messages", FileDiffExtension.messages)
```

Comment: I have tried removing that line and it still gives me issues. I did realize that I needed to move creating my extension out of the task creation in my plugin.. and now my error reads 


 > Could not get unknown property 'getMessages' for extension 'fileDiff' of type com.robschwartz.plugins.filediff.FileDiffExtension.

However the example doesn't show integrating the extension with a task so I think that's where my hang up is now.

Comment: Alright, I have 2 thoughts, one of them - you cannot pass your `Messages` object as a task input. Instead, you have to pass each property of the `Messages` class individually, like `@Input abstract Property<String> message1` and so on. Could you try that?

Comment: You got it! That was it. So this was a good learning experience- you can't pass nested extension objects to tasks (As nice as that would be) but mapping them out in the plugin is sufficient to perform everything you'd need to. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked!